# What is the difference between knowledge-based and R&D?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, firm

So far, I always thought that **knowledge-based companies** and **R&D companies** were the same. But recently our TA mentioned that they are different, I've searched a lot to find the differences between them but the more I searched the less I found.

I would really appreciate if someone told me the difference between these two kind of companies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A knowledge-based company sells products or services that are primarily knowledge-based. This doesn't have to be new knowledge - it can be existing knowledge.

An R&D company earns its way by developing new knowledge.